# Can I preserve a folder's contents in my project directory when I queue a new Build in TFS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a problem. I am using Team Foundation Server 2017 RTM. I have a build definition that will deploy my app to a development server running Windows Server 2012 R2. My app allows users to upload images and PDFs. When this is done, a folder named Media is created in my project's root directory and the files are uploaded here. The problem is, whenever I queue a new build, this folder gets destroyed and all the links to the media don't point to anything. I am rather new at managing and setting up TFS so I was wondering if there is any way I can preserve the contents of my media folder whenever I queue a new build. Any ideas?

Comment: Share the steps you're using to deploy the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, there is a concept of working directory in the build agent.  If you [set clean=true](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#team-foundation-version-control) in  the build definition, this will delete the previous build output when you query a new build. Not sure where you Media folder located, avoid to create/put it in some directory on the build agent such as `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`

> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before
>   being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a.
>
> A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts
>   with the Copy files and Publish build artifacts steps.
>
> **Note:** This directory is **purged before each new build,** so you don't have to clean it up yourself.

More details about the folder path in build/release, you could refer this tutorial-- [Predefined variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#predefined-variables)

Comment: Unfortunately my Media folder is being created in the same directory as Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory and that's why I think it is getting wiped out every time I queue a build. I guess I will have to move my Media folder to somewhere else on the drive to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I spent my whole day looking at this.

In my C# code I create a directory like so:

```
// -- Create a new file name that is unique
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
Guid fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
string fileName = fileGuid + fileExtension;

// -- Create the directory and upload the image to that directory
string mediaDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/Media/");
Directory.CreateDirectory(mediaDirectory);
string filePath = Path.Combine(mediaDirectory, fileName);
upload.SaveAs(filePath);
```

I would then set the image url on the Media object like:

```
string imageUrl = "/Media/" + fileName;
```

So now, instead of storing the image in the database, I am just storing the URL to the image.

---

This was creating the directory in the app directory where I can store the files:

[image: app directory]

Which is cool but as I mentioned, **this directory will be destroyed every time I queue a new build**. How I fixed this was to modify where I stored the images:

```
// -- Create a new file name that is unique
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
Guid fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
string fileName = fileGuid + fileExtension;

// -- Create the directory and upload the image to that directory
// The Media directory will be created on the C drive root
string mediaDirectory = @"c:\Media";
Directory.CreateDirectory(mediaDirectory);
string filePath = Path.Combine(mediaDirectory, fileName);
upload.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Now my Media folder is created on the server's C drive and won't be destroyed whenever I queue a new build. Since the app can't access files outside the app directory, I needed a way to access those files in the Media directory. What I did was create a new virtual folder in IIS that points to the Media folder and gave it the alias Media:

[image: IIS Virtual Directory]

This will now let me have access to all those files I put in the Media directory and will properly display the images when needed. I really hope this helps someone because I spent way too long looking at this.